# html/css How to aling all pictures with same spaces.

Tags: html, css, merge, padding, spacing

I want to make same spacing between all pictures. Their width would be the same only height differs. It should look like in the picture. example: http://prntscr.com/2ugt3z

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like, this will place margin of 5px on every image tag inside #content:

```
#content img{
 margin: 5px;
}
```

or make:

```
.image-margin{
margin: 5px;
}
```

and do something like:

or: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: yes, that is right because some pictures are larger. What if you uses float: left; ?

Answer (score 0):

That kind of layout cannot be done using only floats, your options are:

- Use Flex layout (ie10+)
- Position each element manually
- Use a plugin, if you are using jquery then Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/) are what you need, if you're using pure javascript, Salvattore (http://salvattore.com/) will do the trick.